# Spring AOP and RestEasy ExceptionMapper conflict

Tags: exception, aop, resteasy, spring-aop

I have a ExceptionMapper that I have written for one of my REST resource. I also have a Spring AOP aspect defined for the same resource. Now the problem is ExceptionMapper is not invoked if a REST resource throws an exception. I know this is because of the AOP-proxy objects. (If I remove the aspect it works.) Is there anyway I can make both the ExceptionMapper and the aspect to work.

Comment: anybody has an answer to this....pls...

Comment: Issue is resolved!!!...I had missed to write a try...catch in the Aspect...